# Google sheet script: Getting a list of cell values if a cell in a column is greater than '0'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to send an email from an ordering list in Google Sheets when a button has been clicked. Everything is going well but I need help with one specific part: making a list of all the ordered products.

[image: Google Sheet screenshot]

I added the code below to the button:

```
function sendMyEmails() {
    // Get sheet variables
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Use data from the active sheet
    var Column_E = sheet.getRange("E1:E").getValues();

    var Companyname = sheet.getRange("K3").getValue(); // Company name in veld K3
    var Name = sheet.getRange("K4").getValue(); // Name in cell K4
    var Adress = sheet.getRange("K5").getValue(); // Adress in cell K5
    var Postalcode = sheet.getRange("K6").getValue(); // Postal code in cell K6
    var City = sheet.getRange("K7").getValue(); // City in cell K7
    var Products = ???;

    // Build the email message
    var emailBody =  'Hi,';
    emailBody += '<p>I would like to order:</p>';
    emailBody += '<i>'+ Products + '</i>';
    emailBody += '<p>You can deliver it to:</p>';
    emailBody += '<i>'+ Companyname + '</i><br><i>' + Name + '</i><br><i>' + Adress + '</i><br><i>'+ Postalcode + '</i><br><i>' + City + '</i><br></i>';
          emailBody += '<p>Thanks in advance!</p>';

     // Send the email
     MailApp.sendEmail(
     "email@email.nl", // recipient
      "New order", // subject
      '',                     
     // Body (plain text)
        {
        htmlBody: emailBody    // Options: Body (HTML)
        }
  );
}
```

I want to check column E if there is a value greater than '0' (the amount of products a client wants to order). If a cell in Column E has '1' or higher, the script should take the value of the cell in column K of the same row and put it in the email message (as a list). When 2 products have been ordered the mail should be like:

```
Hi,

I would like to order:

1x article A (value of a cell in column K)
1x article B (value of a cell in column K)

You can deliver it to:

Company
Name
Address
Postal code
City

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Could you share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information)?

Comment: @iamblichus You can find it here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WE2eba9BqiSc15fMbY-b5Bp5mec25iY61fQxnrTUBPA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate through all rows with products, and check, for each row, if the corresponding quantity is higher than 0. If that's the case, the information on the product gets appended to the email body. It could be something along the following lines (check inline comments for more details on what the code is doing at each line):

```js
function sendMyEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Use data from the active sheet  
  // Build the email message:
  var emailBody =  'Hi,';
  emailBody += '<p>I would like to order:</p>';  
  // Build product part:
  var firstRow = 10; // Where product data starts (in your sample, it's row 10)
  var firstCol = 1; // Which column product data starts
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
  var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn() - firstCol + 1;
  // Get all values about product data:
  var productData = sheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues();
  var products = "";
  for (var j = 0; j < productData.length; j++) { // Iterating through all row with product data
    var row = productData[j];
    var quantity = row[4];
    if (quantity > 0) { // Check if quantity is above 0
      var article = row[0];
      // Append product data:
      products += '<i>' + quantity + 'x article number ' + article + '</i><br>';
    }
  }
  emailBody += '<i>'+ products + '</i>'; // Append all product data to the email body
  // Build contact data part:
  var contactData = sheet.getRange("K3:K7").getValues();
  emailBody += '<p>You can deliver it to:</p>';
  for (var i = 0; i < contactData.length; i++) { // Iterating through all contact data
    emailBody += '<i>' + contactData[i][0] + '</i><br>' // Adding contact data to email body
  }
  emailBody += '<p>Thanks in advance!</p>';  
  // Send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    "email@email.nl", // recipient
    "New order", // subject
    '',                     
    // Body (plain text)
    {
      htmlBody: emailBody    // Options: Body (HTML)
    }
  );
}
```

I tested the code and it sent an email like this one:

[image]

#### Notes:

- In this sample I'm not using the data in column K but creating the messages `1x article A` in the script itself (see inline comments).
- In this sample I'm using a loop to add the contact data instead making a `getValue` for each cell and adding all fields to the email body one by one (see inline comments).

#### Reference:

- [getLastRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())
- [getLastColumn](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn)
- [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

I hope this is of any help.